How to stop current audio when clicked next audio?
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
// import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player'
import { useSignedContext } from '../contexts/SignedContext'
import { useParams } from 'react-router'

interface SurahProps {
  name: string
  englishName: string
  englishNameTranslation: string
  number: number
  ayahs: {
    number: number
    text: string
    numberInSurah: number
    audio: string
  }[]
}
interface SetAudiosProps {
  ayahNumber: number
}

const SetAudios: React.FC<SetAudiosProps> = ({ ayahNumber }) => {
  const { surah } = useParams<{ surah: string }>()
  const { selectedAudioFormat } = useSignedContext()
  const [data, setData] = useState<SurahProps[]>([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [currentAudio, setCurrentAudio] = useState<HTMLAudioElement | null>(null)
  const BASE_URL = 'https://api.alquran.cloud/v1/quran/'

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchScholarData() {
      try {
        setLoading(true)
        if (selectedAudioFormat) {
          const response = await fetch(
            `${BASE_URL}/${selectedAudioFormat}`
          ).then((response) => response.json())
          setData(response.data.surahs)
        }
        setLoading(false)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching scholar data:', error)
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }
    fetchScholarData()
  }, [selectedAudioFormat])

  const handleAudioPlay = (audioElement: HTMLAudioElement) => {
    if (currentAudio && currentAudio !== audioElement) {
      currentAudio.pause()
    }
    setCurrentAudio(audioElement)
    audioElement.play()
    console.log(audioElement)
  }


  const filteredData = data.find((surahData) => surahData.englishName === surah)

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }

  if (!selectedAudioFormat) {
    return <p>No translated text available</p>
  }
  return (
    <div className="w-full my-5">
      {filteredData?.ayahs.map((ayah) => {
        // console.log(ayah.audio)
        if(ayah.number === ayahNumber){
          return (
            <audio
              key={ayah.number}
              className="w-full"
              controls
              onPlay={(e) => handleAudioPlay(e.target as HTMLAudioElement)}
            >
              <source src={ayah.audio} />
            </audio>
          )
        }
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SetAudios

// TranslationText.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useSignedContext } from '../contexts/SignedContext'
import SetAudios from './SetAudios'
import { useParams } from 'react-router'
import Loader from './Loader'
interface SurahProps {
  name: string
  englishName: string
  englishNameTranslation: string
  number: number
  ayahs: {
    number: number
    text: string
    numberInSurah: number
  }[]
}

const TranslationText: React.FC = () => {
  const { surah } = useParams<{ surah: string }>()
  const { translatedText } = useSignedContext()
  const [data, setData] = useState<SurahProps[]>([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const BASE_URL = 'https://api.alquran.cloud/v1/quran'

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchScholarData() {
      try {
        setLoading(true)
        if (translatedText) {
          const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/${translatedText}`).then(
            (response) => response.json()
          )
          setData(response.data.surahs)
        }
        setLoading(false)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching scholar data:', error)
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }
    fetchScholarData()
  }, [translatedText])

  if (loading) {
    return <Loader />
  }

  if (!translatedText) {
    return <p className="text-3xl">No translated text available ‍♂️</p>
  }
  const filteredData = data.find((surahData) => surahData.englishName === surah)
  return (
    <>
      {filteredData?.ayahs.map((ayah, i) => (
        <div
          key={ayah.number}
          className="bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg overflow-hidden"
        >
          <div className="px-6 py-4 bg-gray-200">
            <div className="flex gap-5">
              <div className="flex flex-col justify-between">
                <p className="text-3xl font-black">{i + 1}</p>
                <p>
                  <i className="fa-solid fa-share text-3xl"></i>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <i className="fa-solid fa-person-praying text-3xl"></i>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p className="text-2xl">{ayah.text}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <SetAudios ayahNumber={ayah.number} />
          </div>
          <hr className="border-t-4 my-10 border-emerald-700" />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default TranslationText

**Title:** Only One Audio Plays at a Time in React Audio Player Component
**Body:**  Hi Stack Overflow,  I'm working on a React component to display and play audio for each ayah (verse) in a Quran translation app. I'm facing an issue where all selected audio elements play simultaneously instead of only one playing at a time.

Implement an event bus similar to this one here

`<audio
key={ayah.number}
className="w-full"
controls
onPlay={(e) => handleAudioPlay(e.target as HTMLAudioElement)}
onPause={() => setCurrentAudio(null)}



`
**Update currentAudio state when paused**
thanks for your replying but It is not working

I have just written the exact code for it like:
const handleAudioPlay = () => {     document.addEventListener(       'play',       function (e) {         const audiosArr = [...document.getElementsByTagName('audio')]         audiosArr.forEach((audio) => {           if (audio !== e.target) {             audio.pause()           }         })       },       true     )   }
